# Stripe response manipulation in Grails

Tags: grails, stripe-payments

Hi i have the below response for **Stripe** in my Grails 2.5.1 application , how i can read and manipulate it using Grails .

Response :

```
 <com.stripe.model.Charge@1467160391 id=ch_17bcduFKvYH0sAt4OMSKjOzA> JSON: { "amount": 7200, "created": 1454790414, "currency": "egp", "id": "ch_17bcduFKvYH0sAt4OMSKjOzA", "livemode": false, "paid": true, "refunded": false, "disputed": null, "captured": true, "description": "customer@sample.org", "statement_description": null, "failure_message": null, "failure_code": null, "amount_refunded": 0, "customer": null, "invoice": null, "refunds": { "data": [], "total_count": 0, "has_more": false, "url": "/v1/charges/ch_17bcduFKvYH0sAt4OMSKjOzA/refunds", "count": null }, "card": null, "dispute": null, "balance_transaction": "txn_17bcduFKvYH0sAt4qSSDZ7Bj", "metadata": {} }
```

Comment: Listen @Sherif, I'm going to be brutally honest with you. Your questions suggest that you are not doing your part to solve your own problems. Developers around here have either noticed this, or will, and when they do they won't bother to help you. I'm not being mean, just saying it like it is. As for your question, the Stripe Java bindings are an open source project. You can see the Charge class right here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Charge.java

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa , thanks for your comment , but be sure i don't post a question here , unless i failed to find a proper solution for the issue i'm facing as also i'm coming from a different background so this is a learning curve for me in  grails and groovy ,so i hope all be patient with newbies.

Comment: that's good to hear. BTW, I'll be hosting a live Grails coding event next week. You can check it out here: http://emmanuelrosa.com/hangouts/grails/